# Stockfish 11 for Android - binaries

Tags: engines, programming

I have an Android app that uses precompiled binary files of Stockfish. There are both arm64-v8a and armeabi-v7a binary files for direct use in version 10.

On Stockfish site there's however not such an update for latest SF 11 for months!

https://stockfishchess.org/download/

What is the way to go now, are we supposed to wait or is it no longer supported?

I don't want to make any additional steps like compiling source code myself, as long as it's not absolutely necessary. I am currently also not overly interested in supporting custom engines in my app.

I found it to be very comfortable to use these binaries. Or did Android Stockfish turn to something else?

I checked some talk chess forum but I am not part of it, I don't know people there and downloading whatever executable thing from unknown sites just because someone says it's replacement of Stockfish seems a bit loose and unresponsible to users of my app. That's why I am still running on SF10.

Comment: What app are you using? The ["Analyze This"](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pereira.analysis&hl=en) app which has a free version (both for android and ios) is already using SF 11.

Comment: @Phonon I am programming one - Alien Chess.

Comment: If you don't want to be compiling SF 11 yourself then indeed you simply have to wait for the official binaries to be uploaded on their website/Git for SF 11 Android. What is the rush to upgrade your app's engine to SF 11? Why not stick to SF 10 whose strength is more than serviceable for analysis performed at the phone-level...

Comment: @Phonon I am asking where/when/if SF11 binaries will be released. For Windows / Mac / Linux downloads were released almost together while for Android it already takes months.

Comment: When I don't know, you could contact them about it, but where: they will appear both on the download page you linked at and on the git.

Answer (score 3):

Stockfish is a free project, people don't work for financial returns. Unfortunately, that would mean your request might never be honoured. As a programmer with technical skills, you are expected to compile the code yourself.

Sorry, this is how a free open source project work. They give you the code for free, so you just have to do some works.

Comment: Maybe it is like that, I only say it was not like that till last SF10...